# Removing the first occurrence of a character in Twig

Tags: twig

I have string:

```
{% set string = "Sed ut, perspiciatis, unde kim, all." %}
```

How can I remove the first occurrence of a character `,` on the Twig syntax.

After deletion should be:
`Sed ut perspiciatis, unde kim, all.`

Tell me, please, any analogue in Twig syntax for the function of PHP `preg_replace` or some Twig filter:

```
preg_replace('/,/', '', $string, 1);
```

Comment: Add a custom filter to `twig`?

Comment: And without adding a custom filter to Twig?

Comment: Not there is no `preg_replace` support by default. Someone already made a full extension with all the `preg` functions. See [here](https://github.com/victor-sm/Craft-TwigPCRE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split into two part then concatenate it, as example:

```
{% set string = "Sed ut, perspiciatis, unde kim, all." %}

{% set foo = string|split(',', 2) %}


{{ foo[0] ~ foo[1]}}
```

This will output:

> Sed ut perspiciatis, unde kim, all.

[Here](https://twigfiddle.com/3k23kj) a working example

More info on [split here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/split.html)